# Adding a second Wordpress widget

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar

I'm having difficulty with setting up a second sidebar for my Wordpress theme.

Here's the code for function.php:

```
<?php
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){
    register_sidebar(array(
        'before_widget'=>'<li>',
        'after_widget'=>'</li>',
        'before_title'=>'<h2>',
        'after_title'=>'</h2>',
    ))
;
}
?>
<?php
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){
    register_sidebar('home'array(
        'before_widget'=>'<li>',
        'after_widget'=>'</li>',
        'before_title'=>'<h2>',
        'after_title'=>'</h2>',
    ))
;
}
?>
```

This is the error I'm receiving when I try to access the widget options page in admin:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_ARRAY in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tlc\wp-content\themes\tlc\functions.php
>   on line 14

Comment: There is a worpress stack exchange site you should check out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to give it a name you use this syntax

```
 register_sidebar(array(
  'name' => 'RightSideBar',
  'description' => 'Widgets in this area will be shown on the right-hand side.',
  'before_title' => '<h1>',
  'after_title' => '</h1>'
));
```

not what you wrote

see this for more info
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar